# Value number no appear inside js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I don't understand why the `id: ' . $QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id') . '`, does'nt want to take the value of  `$QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id');`

`$QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id')` has value like  2 and 3 but it write always 0.

Any idea ?

Tk

```
     while ($Qspecification->fetch()) {
          $specification_name = $this->productsSpecificationAdmin->getSpecificationName($Qspecification->valueInt('specification_id'), $this->lang->getId());

          $customers_group_id = $Qspecification->valueInt('customers_group_id');

          $QspecificationName = $this->app->db->prepare('select distinct s.specification_id as id,
                                                                         sd.name as name,
                                                                         sgd.name as groupName
                                                         from :table_specification s
                                                                left join :table_specification_group sg ON (s.specification_group_id = sg.specification_group_id )
                                                                left join :table_specification_group_description sgd on (sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id),
                                                             :table_specification_description sd
                                                         where  s.specification_id = sd.specification_id
                                                         and s.specification_id = :specification_id
                                                         and sg.specification_group_id = sgd.specification_group_id
                                                         and sd.language_id = :language_id
                                                         and sgd.language_id = :language_id
                                                       ');
          $QspecificationName->bindInt('specification_id', $Qspecification->valueInt('specification_id'));
          $QspecificationName->bindInt(':language_id', $this->lang->getId());
          $QspecificationName->execute();

          $content .= '<tr id="specification-row' . $t . '">';
          $content .= HTML::hiddenField('id', $Qspecification->valueInt('id'));


          $content .= '  <td>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#specificationName' . $t . '").tokenInput("' . $products_specification_ajax . '" ,
        {
          tokenLimit: 1,
          resultsLimit: 5,
          onResult: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
              value.name = value.id + " " + value.groupName + "/" + value.name;
            });
            return results;
          }
        });
    });



   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#specificationName' . $t . '").tokenInput("' . $products_specification_ajax . '", {
      prePopulate: [
        {
          id: ' . $QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id') . ',
          name: "' . $QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id') . ' ' . $QspecificationName->value('groupName') . '/' . $QspecificationName->value('name') . '"
        }
      ],
      tokenLimit: 1
     });
   });
</script>


}
```

Comment: have you tried parseInt() ?

Comment: You seem to be using a custom database abstraction layer (`bindInt` and `valueInt` aren't native functions). Without seeing the code that defines `valueInt`, it's hard to say what's going on. Also, you mention one place that it's not working, but the same code is also used on the very next line. Is it working there? If not, my guess would be that it has to do with you not doing any sort of `fetch` on your result.

Comment: Probably because you use a column alias -> `s.specification_id as id`

Comment: Also, I see a `$QspecificationName->execute();` but don’t see a `$QspecificationName->fetch();`.

Comment: Ok find the solution :  $Qspecification->valueInt('specification_id') and not $QspecificationName->valueInt('specification_id') . Oups !